# Access Event Loop In Different Process

Tags: python

If I have 2 python processes, the first a script that runs an asyncio eventloop forever, and the second that is an HTTP API server, is there a way to access the event loop of the first process to add tasks to it from endpoints of the API server?

Like a user accesses `/api/example`, and it would add a task, like using `loop.call_soon()` to the event loop.

Is this possible when the 2 processes are executed completely separately?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

I could imagine (depending on what you want exactly and what these tasks are exactly) some kacks / work arounds:

One solution, that you could try is, that there is a connection between the two processes (e.g. a TCP  connection, the asyncio process acting as TCP server, the HTTP server acting as client) where the HTTP server sends enough information over to the asyncio server to create the task and add it to its event loop.

Another option could be, that the http server creates a python file with the code to execute, notifies the asyncio server via a TCP connection or via a signal (e.g. signal HUP) to check in a given directory for a new file, import it and add it to its loop.

Security wise both solutions are a little tricky, as anybody being able to write a file in the specific directory or anybody being able to connect to the TCP socket might trigger an action.

But all depends on your context.

Or you could try to start the HTTP API server as a thread in the same process as your asyncio process?

Comment: The current workaround I'm using is starting the process that I don't have manual control over the loop, but have access to the loop.  I then use the other processes' `set_event_loop` function to the first's loop.  This allows them both to access it, but it isn't kosher by any means.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you talking about processes or about threads?

At the moment I do not see how your workaround could even work.
event loops are objects in RAM, each process should have its own variables so I'd expect that `set_event_loop()`

Perhaps you could post a small example of your workaround in your question?